# Pre-define custom scripts to run on Azure Container Service cluster VMs

Tags: azure, docker-swarm, azure-container-service

I would like to provide some pre-defined scripts which need to be run in Azure Container Service Swarm cluster VMs. Is there a way I can provide these pre-defined scripts to ACS, so that when the cluster is deployed, this pre-defined scripts automatically gets executed in all the VMs of that ACS cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a supported feature of ACS, though you can run arbitrary scripts on the VMs once created. Another option is to use ACS Engine which allows much more control over the configuration of cluster as it outputs templates that you can configure. See http://github.com/Azure/acs-engine.